# Why has "Shop by ..." disappeared when using ElasticSearch?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, search, extensions

I just finished setting up ElasticSearch with my Magento store. I've used [magento-elasticsearch](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-elasticsearch) for this.

The search is much better compared to the default search engine.

But for some reason the "Shop by ..." on the left side has disappeared.

This is what it looked like with the default search:
[image]

This is what it looks like with ElasticSearch:
[image]

How can I get it back?

(Magento 1.9.0.1 with ElasticSearch 1.3.2)

Comment: Have you checked with the Elastic Search Github help? https://github.com/jreinke/magento-elasticsearch/issues

Comment: Check to see if the module config has a choice to enable/disable the Layered Search Navigation block or if any layout updates used by this feature remove the block. It may not be compatible with Layered Navigation. It rewrites the block with Bubble_Search_Block_Catalogsearch_Layer

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem so it must be environment specific. All I know is that the Github documentation tells you that you have to use elasticsearch 0.20.x and that higher versions are supported in the payed version. Maybe this is part of the problem? I use 0.20.x. Furthermore you should check for rewrite conflicts / layout xml like @FiascoLabs stated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.